# Auto connect plugged in ethernet with dual NIC

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have a machine that I will be deploying that has a dual NIC setup (unecessarily I might add...). I need them to be able to boot straight up and have internet from a freshly cloned disk, but I cannot be 100% sure that all of the machines will have their network cable plugged into the same port.

Right now I have it set up so it attempts to connect via DHCP for both interfaces and this works, but it causes systemd to hang for 5 minutes on boot trying to raise both interfaces. This is not a showstopper, but it is annoying and I would like to fix it.

I know I can use `ethtool` to see if a link is detected, but how can I tie this into the ubuntu networking setup to only try to connect the interface that is plugged in?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222185).

Using `allow-hotplug enp2s0` instead of `auto enp2s0` for both interfaces works.